# Local gulp won't update

Tags: sass, gulp

I have to use gulp with project, but the problem is that the local Gulp version is 3.8.11 and the global is 3.9.0. It doesn't matter how much I update it stays the same. I'm on windows 7.

Did this:

```
npm update gulp -g
cd myfolder
npm update gulp
```

I've also tried reinstalling a bunch of times but in the end it always comes up with:

```
CLI version 3.9.0
Local version 3.8.11
```

Any ideas how to start solving this?

Comment: What version is referenced in your `package.json`

Comment: Try to do something like that: ````npm update gulp -save````

Answer (score 0):

`npm update gulp -g` will always update the global copy.
The warning is for your gulp in `node_modules/gulp` in your local project.

Navigate to your local project in terminal and do `npm install gulp --save`.